# servlet version getServletContext().getEffectiveMajorVersion() given me 2.5 while i am using 3

Tags: java, servlets

i am using tomcat 7.0.11 which also support servlet 3.0 but

`req.getServletContext().getEffectiveMajorVersion()`  // 2

`req.getServletContext().getEffectiveMinorVersion()`  // 5

gives me this output.

how would i achive servlet 3.0?

it show **jsp 2.1 while i expect 2.2** as tomcat support javaServer page 2.2.

and also how would i get JAvaServer Page version?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `web.xml` specifies Servlets 3.0:

```
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- snip -->

</web-app>
```

To get the version of JSP that you're using, use the [`javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory.html):

```
 JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getEngineInfo().getSpecificationVersion();
```

Comment: how would i ensure  that i'm using which J2ee version ?

Comment: thanks @Matt Ball. i got it. but one more que. as my tomcat support JavaServer Pages 2.2, `JspFactory` gives me 2.1.

Comment: Did you already make sure that the deployment descriptor specifies Servlets 3.0? Either way, you're not going to notice much difference between JSP 2.1 and 2.2, since 2.2 is just a maintenance release.

Comment: see my edit i uploaded image for JSP version. and `xmlns:web` which points to `"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"`
while `xsi:schemaLocation` is also point to `"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"`.

Comment: Like I said, I wouldn't worry about JSP 2.1 vs 2.2.